# Where should I add the magic comment of lexical-binding?

Tags: elisp, lexical-scope

The first line of a .el file used to be

```
;;; foo.el - a foo package
```

Does it works if the magic comment is added after this?

```
;;; foo.el - a foo package
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

Or even later in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Using Lexical Binding`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Specifying File Variables`

This *must* be in the first line. An exception is made for shell scripts (only), where it may alternatively be on the second line.

Note that, unlike other file-local vars, `lexical-binding` can *only* appear in this first-line listing.

Comment: Could I do like this `;;; foo.el - a foo package    -*- lexical-binding: t -*-` on the first line?

Comment: Yes you can. Note that if you use `M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line` it will do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is

```
;;; <FILE> --- <DESCRIPTION>  -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
```